# Missing rows in outer join have zero value for float column instead of null - why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2000

I'm using Microsoft's SQL Server 2000 and have a query that is essentially this (except that Z is a further subquery, not a table):

```
select 
  A.key1,
  A.key2,
  B.value1
from A
left join (select * from Z where value1 > 0) B 
  on A.key1 = B.key1 and A.key2 = B.key2
order by A.key1, B.key1
```

Column value1 is of type float. For some reason, instead of returning NULL where rows don't exist in subquery B, value1 is set to 0.0.

I worked around it, but can anyone suggest why this happens? Is it a known feature/bug of SQL Server?

Comment: Just hint: you use "order by A.key1, B.key1" when you have "A.key1=B.key1"? You can omit B.key1 in the order section.

Comment: Oops, that was a mistype, I meant to put order by A.key1, A.key2

Comment: This is what would happen in Java if you called ResultSet.getFloat("value1") because it can't return null.  You have to call wasNull() afterward to check whether it was actually null.  Could it be that you're in a similar situation?

Comment: SQL Server most certainly should not put zeroes in there. Have you confirmed this behaviour via Query Analyzer? Also, you may want to check if ANSI_NULLS is enabled for the connection.

Comment: Yes I'm using Query Analyzer. I'll edit the original post to include the entire query and sample data.

Answer (score 2):

Floats are not exact, so the value might be slightly larger than 0 but still display as 0.  Does it help if you change the query to:

```
left join (select * from Z where value1 > 0.000001) B
```

EDIT: After your comment, I checked on a SQL Server 2000 machine:

```
select t2.col2
from (select 1 as col1) t1
left join (select cast(1.0 as float) as col2) as t2 on 1=0
```

This displays `NULL`, not `0.0`, for me.  What tool are you using to run the query?

Comment: I see what you mean but if I run just "select * from Z where value1 > 0" the rows that have 0.0 in the above query don't exist. Also if I specify B.* in the original query it shows that all other columns in B (which are varchar(n)) are NULL but the float value1 is 0.0.

Comment: I'm using the Query Analyzer. I'll edit the original post to show my entire query and some sample data.